# How to print a Local URL via Google Cloud Print

Tags: javascript, cordova, google-cloud-print

I'm developing a cordova app and I need to print a dynamic page via GoogleCloudPrint.
I've tried both a demo URL on the web and a local URL on the device but in both cases console told me:
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'h' of null at https://www.google.com/cloudprint/client/869201922-dialog_mobile.js:282

Here's the code

```
function createPDF(){
    $('#footerprint').hide();
    gadget.setPrintDocument("url", "Audit", "print.html");
    gadget.openPrintDialog();
    }
```